# Why is drinking beer after wine a bad idea?

Tags: inebriation

As the well known rhyme reminds us, drinking beer after wine is a bad idea. Having made the mistake during my student years more than once and regretting it, why is it that consuming these two beverages in the wrong order causes such effects?

Comment: Beer before liquor never been sicker.. liquor before beer your in the clear

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Beer contains a lot of CO2, and CO2 causes the alcohol to 'hit to the head' much faster. This is why champagne has such exhilaration (Rausch) effect.

It's not a good idea to drink any high-CO2 drink after drinking wine or stronger alcohols, and even more discouraged is mixing carbonated water with vodka, for example. Many people have heavily regret such mixing.

As well, it is said you should never drink lighter alcohols after stronger. You can start with beer, than after an hour/2 drink some wine, rest and drink vodka. Never opposite. But the best is to keep one genre of alcohol on one evening. At least so are saying people in Poland.

Comment: Do you have any links that back up your claim that CO2 causes alcohol to go to your head faster? Also, you may want to consider removing your last paragraph; you're giving advice that's based solely on opinion, and it's irrelevant to the question. (And also wrong: when I go out, I often have a pre-dinner drink with a strong alcohol, then switch to beer or wine later in the evening, with no ill effects or regret.)

Comment: @Laura well no, it's just what are people saying. At least in Poland. And they are referencing their own experience. I've modified the question to stress out it's only said it's so.

Comment: I'm not sure about not drinking lighter (weaker) alcoholic drinks after stronger ones. I've always thought the opposite: bad things happen if you have a few beers and then start drinking something strong like whiskey or vodka, because it's very easy to drink too much of the stronger liquor since you're already a bit inebriated.

Comment: @Laura, here's a link I found quickly from NIH in the US, which backs up the assertion though not with a link to research.  http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/001944.htm

Comment: That carbonation increases alcohol absorption seems to be pretty common knowledge though.

Comment: I think the big issue is the carbonation.  Drink wiskey and beer in any order and that's going to be an issue.  I am not at all sure that the order of strength matters.

Comment: @Laura If you go out and have a pre-dinner drink and then switch to beer or wine later in the evening you probably have not drank much.   It is not evidence CO2 does not cause alcohol hit the head faster.

Comment: @ChrisTravers There is noting in the article you about carbonation.   Carbohydrate is different and it states that can slow down absorption.

Comment: Paparazzi has it correct, @ChrisTravers : that article does not support the hypothesis that CO2 causes alcohol to absorb into the blood more quickly. (the only sentence that contains the string 'carb' is this: "high-carbohydrate and high-fat foods can make your body absorb alcohol more slowly."). Frankly, this idea seems like rank superstition.

Comment: Lots of opinion but little science. Nice cultural reference though.

Answer (score 12):

I have never seen anything solid backing up *any* rhyme that encourages a particular order.

When it comes to intoxication, there are two things that are definitely relevant:

- The total amount of alcohol consumed
- How fast the alcohol is absorbed

As far as I am concerned, the rest is hearsay and folklore.

There may be some auxiliary "explanations", like people who mix types being more likely to drink more overall, and people drinking different types of alcohol at different rates at different stages of intoxication, but these are not chemical qualities.

[Here's one NYT article backing this up](http://www.nytimes.com/2006/02/07/health/07real.html?_r=0). I'm having a hard time finding credible scientific articles about intoxication.

Answer (score 6):

#### EDIT to add sources (original answer below)

Mythbusters address this in episode 127 - http://mythresults.com/dirty-vs-clean-car - the *rate* of consumption is what matters, not the *order*

> #### A hangover caused by beer is less severe than one caused by a mixture of beer and liquor.
>
> ### BUSTED
>
> To perform this test, Tory and Grant would have to eat the same food, drink their alcohol at the same time, and sleep for the same length of time in the warehouse for consistent results. Kari (who could not take part because of her pregnancy) then devised a battery of tests to measure dehydration, memory, light/sound/motion sensitivity, and coordination. Without having drunk alcohol, Tory and Grant performed well on their control test. They then performed the beer test, with Tory drinking 14 cans of beer and Grant drinking six. They both performed significantly worse than the control tests, signifying they were badly hung over. They then repeated the test with a mixture of beer and liquor, making sure to drink an equivalent amount of alcohol as in the first test. The next morning, Tory and Grant improved significantly and felt much better than in the previous test. Thus, the Build Team declared the myth busted.

NYTimes also addressed this back in 2006 - http://www.nytimes.com/2006/02/07/health/the-claim-mixing-types-of-alcohol-makes-you-sick.html

> "The pattern, more often, is that people will have beer and then move on to liquor at the end of the night, and so they think it's the liquor that made them sick," he continued. "But simply mixing the two really has nothing to do with it."

---

In general, the ABV of wine is higher than that of beer, so if you consume a higher ABV after a lower ABV, you will feel its effects faster, but if you're still drinking at the same rate, you won't notice you've had any effect as readily as if you drank at the slower rate more generally associated with the higher ABV beverage.

Comment: I think the question was why drinking beer *after* wine is a bad idea.

Comment: @DanielHedberg - and there I go being dyslexic again :)

Comment: What is the meaning of AB ?

Comment: @HiteshSahu - ABV is "alcohol by volume"

Answer (score 3):

This seems to more myth than fact.  I am not finding anything scientific that CO2 causes faster absorption.

If that was the case you would see carbonated fitness drinks for faster absorption.

There are studies that Champagne go to the head faster but it also has a lot of sugar.

The more like causality is people that mix also just plain drink more.

For me personally I like a shot (or two) of tequila first to get a buzz and then sip beer.  I am more likely to burn (most) of it off by the time I go to bed.  If you have a belly full of beer there is just a volume of liquid for the body to process and hard liquor on top is just more liquor.  You can get stupid with a few beer and then just get even way more stupid with shots as you are numb and the beer dilutes the alcohol so you don't feel the boom.  Shots early and you have more immediate and clear feedback you are over drinking.

As for wine it has about the same effect on me and the alcohol difference is not that great.   I just don't like the taste of mixing them in one evening.

There are studies that higher percentage drinks are absorbed faster and it make sense as the body is processing a smaller volume for the alcohol.

Answer (score -2):

simple answer here.

Drinking beer after any other alcohol makes you feel NOT thirsty and therefore you don't feel the urge to drink water before going to bed.

If you drank a more concentrated alcohol after beer you would be thirsty before going to sleep and would drink some.

Contrary to the popular belief, beer is a dehydrating drink. After drinking beer you water balance is negative, you actually need to drink some water. And drinking beer after any other alcohol makes the dehydration problem 1.worse and 2.unnoticed.

Comment: While your final paragraph is correct, your first two don't seem to have much basis in fact. Do you have a citation or some evidence?

Comment: My first and second paragraphs are based solely on my opinion formed after years of practical experiments, my friend.

Comment: If you quench your thirst with a dehydration drink you are going to have a bad time the day after.  Not many people will force themself to drink a considerable amount of water after their beer

Answer (score -3):

The two don't mix. Beer is heavy, and wine is lighter in consistency, which would make it hard on your stomach, kidneys and liver to de-toxify.
Wine also contains sulfites, which by themselves can make you sick.

Comment: Do you have any *reliable sources* for your claims? This sounds like homeopathic fluff